# Workspaces or fullscreen only in secondary monitor?

Tags: gnome, wine, multiple-monitors, workspaces, fullscreen

I am working with two monitors, big and small. I use big as my primary and small is the one I use most to reference stuff.

The issue is that workspaces only switch the view on the primary and leave the secondary static. And full screen aplications (like games) or certain wine programs (that I need to use often) also default to the primary.

So, what I would like is to keep Big static with only one workspace, but make fullscreen games and stuff default to it. And give the multiple workspaces to Small. Either by making secondary monitor the multiple workspaces or by making Small the primary and making the secondary default for fullscreens.

**TLDR:** *How to make only the secondary monitor switch workspaces?
And if not possible, how to make games and wine aplications default to secondary monitor?*

Comment: Make the secondary primary, and the primary (small screen) the secondary monitor? btw, why the tag "wine"?

Comment: @vanadium Because those are the fullscreen aplications that give me most trouble. Native linux apps usually let me pick wich monitor to use, but wine stuff (like steam games or certain windows apps) defaults to primary and i cant figure out how to put them in fullscreen (or even maximize them in some cases) to the second.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution but a workaround since I also want the same as you, to have workspaces only on the second monitor for full screen applications.

First enable "Workspaces on all displays" in Gnome Settings. Then,you can right click on the title bar of applications that you want to stay on the primary monitor and select "Always on Visible Workspace".

It's not pretty since you can't just drag to the primary display and make them stay there and also the Super and Super + A animations will show all the workspaces on the primary display with the same repeated content, but it works for working with full screen vm's or sharing the secondary display while you have a "static" main display.